# Mockery throws NoMatchingExpectationException when testing Laravel facade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit, mockery

I'm trying to test one of my service classes but can't get a PHPUnit test to pass.

The relevant part of the test that is failing:

```
File::shouldReceive('put')->with('app/storage/logs/laravel.log', 'New content.')->once()->andReturn(12);
```

The code I'm trying to test (simplified version):

```
$date = Carbon::now()->toDayDateTimeString();
$fileContent = sprintf(
    "Last maintenance check performed at %s. The old logs have been deleted.\n\n",
    $date
);

// $this->fileLocation refers to a string 'app/storage/logs/laravel.log'
return File::put($this->fileLocation, $fileContent);
```

The exception that I'm getting:

```
Time: 1.72 seconds, Memory: 17.50Mb

There was 1 error:

1) Unit\Services\Maintenance\LogCleanerTest::testLogsAreClearedAndUpdated
Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException: No matching handler found for Mockery_0_Illuminate_Filesystem_Filesystem::put("app/storage/logs/laravel.log", "Last maintenance check performed at Tue, Jul 15, 2014 12:16 PM. The old logs have been deleted.
"). Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument list for this method


/home/vagrant/Code/MyApp/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/ExpectationDirector.php:93
/home/vagrant/Code/MyApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:211
/home/vagrant/Code/MyApp/app/Code/Services/Maintenance/LogCleaner.php:19
/home/vagrant/Code/MyApp/app/Code/Services/Maintenance/LogCleaner.php:19
/home/vagrant/Code/MyApp/app/tests/Unit/Services/Maintenance/LogCleanerTest.php:30
/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:179
/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:132
```

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
File::shouldReceive('put')->with('app/storage/logs/laravel.log', 'Last maintenance check performed at')->once()->andReturn(12);
```

Should work. You're telling mockery to expect 'New Content.' as the second parameter, but your code is sending 'Last maintenance check...'. I believe mockery will try a regex match by default if it can't match the exact string.

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to get the test to pass now, however it only happens when both strings are an exact match. Any other idea how to get the Mockery to recognize partial text matches (or if it's even possible)?

Comment: @kajetons the whole point is the test should give you an *exact match* to what you expect, otherwise that might be a sign there is a bug.

Comment: There are other ways to write the expectation so that you don't need an exact match. See the excellent [mockery documentation](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/). However, as @TheShiftExchange notes, the point is that your output matches what you expect, so use these methods carefully.